# Custom WooCommerce ordering for categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce 3.4.3 and Advanced Custom Fields.  For the default across the site I'm sorting the products by price high to low.  On a specific category (which has an ID of 87) I want to be able to search by the ACF relationship that I've established, which has a meta_key of bases_ordering.  Here's the code I've made so far but can't figure out why it's wrong or how to filter it properly.

Any help you have to offer would be greatly appreciated!

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
// do not modify queries in the admin
if( is_admin() ) {
    return $query;
}

// only modify queries for 'event' post type
if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'product' && $query->query_vars['tag_ID'] === 87 ) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');   
    $query->set('meta_key', 'bases_ordering');   
    $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
}

// return
return $query;
} 
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Comment: Are you referring to the main products section on a *product category* page [like this one](https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/product-category/clothing/)?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to any product category like you showed me (such as product-category/clothing/ or product-category/kitchen/).